# How it is possible for JVM, to react on user's requests

Tags: java, servlets, jvm

Let's take spring application that is embedded in some tomcat container for example. I know that spring uses servlets under it's mask but I want to understand how it works internally, from JVM point of view. What communicates directly with JVM?

Standalone "static" application case is simple because code is compiled once, bytecode is interpreted by JVM/compiled by JIT, class are loaded and there is no interaction with the outside world - we can say that application is "invoked once" when started.

But when it comes to application that can have some interaction with user and so on, running in loop, using i.e. spring, how JVM knows that some methods were invoked by requesting i.e. "localhost:8080/users"? JVM is listening on some port? Reading from socket? Which component is responsible for it?

I would be very grateful for writing the whole path from the start of the application, user request to the interaction with JVM and what is happening on it.

Comment: I think you need more clarity on what you are asking. Broadly speaking there is a chain:
user browser -> user network -> server os -> jvm native code -> java code. What part of the chain are you interested in exactly?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I could have been more specific. It is really hard to explain for me. What I am asking basically is, how external actions (like i.e. querying spring's endpoint or clicking button in GUI coded in JavaFx) leads to REAL TIME method's invocations on JVM (some kind of JVM I/O). I hope I made it clearer, if not, I will try again.

Comment: So idk exactly how spring does this, but in general for platform specific handling of IO in java, there is native code which does the needed syscalls and then uses JNI or similar to communicate that back to java code.

Comment: To clarify JNI allows native code to make java function calls from native code.

Comment: Okay, I tried to connect JNI with Spring somehow during my investigation and that was the closest thing that matched my questions. So, thank you very much for making this clear for me and convincing me in this.

Comment: Spring is just using a lot of reflections, to scan for possible methods to execute, but otherwise its normal code, that just reads data from sockets and then looks for matching handler to execute it based on data from annotations. No special JVM related things are used here. JVM does not know anything about "what methods to execute" when request comes. And it all goes to just reading data from raw socket like explained in answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, your question is very broad and not suitable for StackOverflow.

In short, the JVM is no special from any other operating system process here. You (or your vendor) writes a Java/C/Go/Python/whatever code which listens on a *socket*.

When an incoming network request comes, the operating system "notifies" the process (your running program) that there are new data so it can interpret it and react in whatever way it wants (such as saving user data into a database and returning a proper response).

The Java/JVM code for interacting with operating system specific facilities like *sockets* are written in *native* code (that is C/C++) and provided by JVM to your Java program via wrappers ("native methods").
As an example there's an internal `PlainSocketImpl.java` class with a bunch of native methods implemented in the corresponding `PlainSocketImpl.c` native code: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/PlainSocketImpl.c
(e.g. the `socketAccept` implementation: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk14/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/PlainSocketImpl.c)

I suggest you find a good resource on general socket programming; you may find these useful:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Comment: I couldn't be more specific in this topic and I really tried to find some answers in the Internet but without good results, so I asked on StackOverflow in a way I could. I thought this was the best place where someone can give me a hint where to look.

Comment: Did my answer help you to at least somewhat understand what's going on and where to find more help?